# Entity Framework Core domain and classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently following a project being developed by csharpfritz (of microsoft). It's called, "corewiki". Some form of "wikipedia" like project.
Here's the link to the repository on github: [CoreWiki by Jeff Fritz](https://github.com/csharpfritz/CoreWiki) 
On the domain class for comments he writes this:

I'm trying to understand why he created an entity **FromDomain** class and **ToDomain** class:

```
// Main model

public class CommentDAO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ArticleDAO Article { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Instant Submitted { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}


public static CommentDAO FromDomain(Core.Domain.Comment comment)
{
    return new CommentDAO
    {
        AuthorId = comment.AuthorId,
        Content = comment.Content,
        DisplayName = comment.DisplayName,
        Email = comment.Email,
        Id = comment.Id,
        ArticleId = comment.ArticleId,
        Submitted = comment.Submitted
    };
}

public Core.Domain.Comment ToDomain()
{
    return new Core.Domain.Comment
    {
        AuthorId = AuthorId,
        Content = Content,
        DisplayName = DisplayName,
        Email = Email,
        Id = Id,
        ArticleId = this.Article.Id,
        Submitted = Submitted
    };
}
```

Comment: Aks them. We can only share our own opinion, which is "off-topic" at Stack Overflow.

Comment: He's separating the DAO (Data Access Objects) from the Domain Objects. SEe [Having the domain model separated from the persistence model](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/)

Comment: Maybe, but DAO is a deceptive misnomer, seeing the [common definition of DAO](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm).

Answer (score 2):

That's simply mapping code to map a domain model to a data access object and vice versa. You can implement this in many ways, such as the author showed, or using explicit conversion operators, or using a tool like AutoMapper.

See for example [Having the domain model separated from the persistence model](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/) (first Google hit for "why separate domain model from dao") for an explanation of why you'd want that.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. My confusion arose because he also used AutoMapper even after he did this domain map to data acess object.

Comment: Using `AutoMapper` on top of this is probably a bit of overkill, but it does serve to abstract out the actual API methods (`ToDomain`/`FromDomain`). That may have been the intention: keep the mapping logic with the domain, but still keep the app agnostic about the whole shebang.